# window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight, is the margin top or bottom?

Tags: javascript, dom

Consider this image:

[image]

Is there any way for me to know where the difference between outerHeight and innerHeight went? (In this case, say 100 px top and 16 px bottom).

Comment: In IEs `topHeight = screenTop - screenY`, in FF `topHeight = mozInnerScreenY - screenY`. Unfortenately it seems that Chrome gives the same value for `screenY` and `screenTop`.

Comment: Wow, great! Just need a Mozilla specific solution for now so this is awesome.